# How long does an owl live?

Tags: jokes

I've seen the following joke on [Pinterest](http://www.strangebeaver.com/2016/04/tumblr-tuesday-4-19/).

> - How long does an owl live?
> - Six and a half books.

I don't get it. Googling gave me no connotations to the context that I recognized as related or relevant.

Comment: I think it's a reference to the Harry Potter books.  Try googling "does harry potter owl die".

Comment: "How much cocaine did Charlie Sheen take?"  "Enough to kill two-and-a-half men."

Comment: @Malvolio That was funny. Probably equally funny as the owl joke but it this case, I was well aware of the reference as I loved that show.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Harry Potter and The Deathly Hollows" is the seventh Harry Potter book, which features the [Battle of The Seven Potters](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_the_Seven_Potters) in which Hedwig, Harry's owl, dies.

The joke is funny because the punchline is unexpected; to answer a question of age with an unusual unit, books. Of course, no longer funny when explained and analyzed.

Comment: it would be funny if the timeline adds up, as in, the time between the release of the first book, to somewhere between the sixth and seventh is somewhat the lifetime of an owl

Comment: @klskl considering how this isn't the real world, his owl could as well have died in any age. Owls can live up to 30-something years, so I guess that could fit.